# window.navigator vs window.clientInformation

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

I just want to know if there are any differences (i.e. for compatibility) by using `window.navigator` over `window.clientInformation`. Both of those JavaScript objects contains the client language (`window.clientInformation.language` and `window.navigator.language`) or the user agent (`window.clientInformation.userAgent` and `window.navigator.userAgent`).

I already have tried to google the answer but didn't got any statisfying answers. Is `window.clientInformation` just an historical leftover, since no major source mentions its use for solving any problem? Is `window.clientInformation` just an alias for `window.navigator`?

Comment: navigator is the correct one, clientInformation was an IE thing.  Even though some browsers support that too, navigator is the standard.

Comment: window.clientInformation seems to be an internet explorer/edge "thing" - the fact that it's in edge suggests micro$oft haven't abandoned it

Comment: Unfortunately window.navigator shows the incorrect preferred language sometimes in IE/Edge, when it seems to work properly in Chrome.

Comment: @Brain2000 Can you please explain 'sometimes'?

Comment: @Wolle Based on customer reports, there have been cases where it is correct, and cases where it is incorrect. I haven't spent the time to track down the why. If I had to guess, it might vary based on the region or version of IE/Edge.